# error: no matching function for call to , in static function

Tags: c++

I have a class named Book that contains an object from class Author. Book's constructor is a private field so I can not use the this class to define objects, so I have another class called BookBuilder which friend to Book and Author helps me to do this.

If I remove the static function problem disappears.

The problem is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Author :: Author ()
```

In fact I do not have the Author default constructor

```
class Book {

public:

    friend class BookBuilder;
    // ...  other functions
private:

    Book(const std::string title, const std::string publisher,const Author& author, const std::string genre, int isbn, double price):title_(title),publisher_(publisher),author_(author),isbn_(isbn),price_(price),genre_(genre){}
    std::string title_;
    std::string publisher_;
    Author author_;
    double price_;
    int isbn_;
    std::string genre_;
};
```

---

```
class BookBuilder {

public:

    static BookBuilder start(){return BookBuilder();}
    // ... other functions

private:
    std::string title_;
    std::string publisher_;
    Author author_;
    double price_;
    int isbn_;
    std::string genre_;
};
```

Comment: _"error: no matching function for call to 'Author :: Author () | In fact I do not have the department Auhtor Default Constructor"_ Okay well didn't you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BookBuilder::start` method is

```
static BookBuilder start(){ return BookBuilder(); }
```

This will try to return a default-constructed `BookBuilder`. This class has a member

```
Author author_;
```

So when you try to construct a `BookBuilder`, it will try to default initialize the members, including default initializing your `auther_` in this case. Therefore `Author` needs a default constructor for this to work.

Comment: What if I can't add a Default constructor, there is another way to deal with this !?

Comment: If you can't add a default constructor to `Author`, then `BookBuilder`'s default constructor needs to use whatever constructor is available to construct its `Author` member.